# MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches PrimaryServerSelector

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, exception

I get this error

> com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while
> waiting for a server that matches PrimaryServerSelector. Client view
> of cluster state is { type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
> exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening
> socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
> connect}}]

after third line of below code

```
 MongoCollection<Document> grid = mongodb.getCollection("grid");
 Document doc = Document.parse(json);
 grid.insertOne(doc);
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you share how are you creating the mongo client? I mean the connection string etc. Also would be good to check if the mongo cluster is working or not. Please ensure if you are using SSL connection, you have certificate, username password added correctly while creating the mongo client

Comment: Did you initiate the replica set?